# psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ON"

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-3.0

I am trying Django from Django documentation.
I created two classes in models.py on my polls app: `Publication` and `Articles`, with a many-to-many field:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    publications=models.ManyToMany(Publication, ...)
```

Then in *python shell*, I imported ran:

```
>>> from polls.models import Publication,Articles
>>> p1=Publication.objects.get(id=1)
>>> p2=Publication.objects.get(id=2)
>>> p3=Publication.objects.get(id=3)
>>> a1=Articles(headlines="When will be the lockdown get finished?")
>>> a1.publications.add(p1)
```

and I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ..." ("articles_id", "publication_id") VALUES (2, 1) ON CONFLIC...
```

Comment: Please share the query

Comment: @Gabip the OP isn't running a query directly, it is generated by the `a1.publications.add(p1) ` line.

Answer (score 4):

[Django 3.0 supports PostgreSQL 9.5 and higher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes). You are getting that error because you are using an earlier version of PostgreSQL that does not support `ON CONFLICT`.

To resolve the issue, you could either upgrade PostgreSQL, or downgrade to the latest Django 2.2.X, which supports PostgreSQL 9.4 and higher.